# Cannot access Properties page of a database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, corruption

I'm in the process of decommissioning a database server and migrating the databases from one server to another.  I was attempting to get the the properties of the database and received a SQL Error popup.

*Property Owner is not available for Database '[database name]'.  This property may not exist for this object, or may not be retrievable due to insufficient access rights.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)*

Facts:

- Server 2003 Standard with SP2
- SQL Server 2005 Standard - 9.0.1399
- I'm a sysadmin, so it shouldn't be perms issue
- Had another sysadmin perform the operation with the same error
- DBCC CheckDB listed no errors
- Able to backup w/o error
- Took DB offline/online w/o error

Any suggestions or tests that I can perform and report on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could probably have just set the database owner to `[sa]` (or any valid login really) rather than detach / re-attach.

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::dbname TO [sa];
```

This probably happened because the login responsible for creating, attaching or restoring the database initially no longer exists. The UI isn't smart enough to fail gracefully when there isn't a valid owner.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue, but not sure what caused the problem.

I detached/reattached the database and then was able to access the database properties.

It appears that this database lost its owner somehow.  How does that even happen?!

Comment: The database owner might have been John Smith. John was a contractor who has now left. The system finally cottons on to his non-existence. I would not recommend detaching / reattaching - a bit risky if Aaron's solution does the trick